# Modify default behavior in drag and drop of files in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

In TeXShop, when you drag and drop a file from Finder into your document, TeXShop recognizes the type of file and wraps around relevant LaTeX syntax to help make sure it compiles.

Example 1:
The image file `/home/dir/imagefile.png` becomes

`\includegraphics[]{/home/dir/imagefile.png}`

Example 2:
The mp4 file `/home/dir/moviefile.mp4` becomes

`\input{/home/dir/moviefile.mp4}`

Is there a way to change this default behavior?

For example, I would like to modify `\includegraphics[]{/home/dir/imagefile.png}` so that it becomes `\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{/home/dir/imagefile.png}`.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd assume it's hard coded so can't be changed.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense...it is a nifty feature regardless

Comment: You can set options for graphics inclusion globally via e.g. `\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\linewidth}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in the comments.